# Simulate synchronous user interaction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a series of questions I want to ask the user, with later questions depending on earlier ones. These are expressed most concisely by pretending we can have synchronous i/o, like this:

```
//'queryuser' is a callback which provides synchronous user interaction
function seriesOfQuestions(queryuser)
    var drink = queryuser("What would you like to drink?",["Tea","Coffee","Orange Juice"]);
    if (drink=="Tea" || drink=="Coffee")
    {
        var milk = queryuser("Would you like milk?",["Yes","No"]);
        var sugar = queryuser("Would you like sugar?",["Yes","No"]);
        if (milk=="Yes")
            var milk_type = queryuser("Normal or soya?",["Moo juice","Hippy beans"]);
    }
    queryuser("Would you like a biscuit?",["Yes","No"]);
    //...etc... deep decision tree, though note code paths can re-join for biscuits
}
```

Javascript, of course, doesn't work like this; functions such as `$ionicPopup.show()` do not block execution and instead themselves call a callback (via a promise mechanism) when the user selects an option. So if we use `ionicPopup.show` for `queryuser` we'll get all the popups at once, and the decision tree will be executed on `null` return values.

Is there a way we can wrap `ionicPopup.show()` or similar in a function that behaves like we want `queryuser` to behave?

(Preferably less obtuse than Duff's device for writing C co-routines...)

Or failing that, how can a decision tree like the above be expressed without ending deep in callback hell?

Comment: Why not just use es6 Promises? Use series of `.then` which would `resolve()` on popup close and can also take output of previous step(s) to calculate how to behave

Comment: You can probably keep track of state by assigning decisions to an object, and then passing that object down the promise chain. That way you don't end up nesting your callbacks.

Comment: @Mirko I'm thinking of this but where would I keep e.g. the `milk` variable above?

Comment: @4castle this would seem to be the brute force approach but adds a lot of boilerplate to pass all the state down the stack as we go

Comment: @SideshowBob, I'd pass it down as output to the next `then` step if needed only there. otherwise store it in an object available to all the steps. it's a little late here and I'm just thinking loud, not enough to write an answer. BTW, you can also nest `then` steps.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [ES8 `async`/`await`](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) if your queries are returning promises.

But since you were asking about coroutines, you can also use generator functions and drive them asynchronously by a query framework. Especially [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) allows a nice abstraction of an asynchronous user interface.